# Differences between static libraries and dynamic libraries ignoring how they are used by the linker/loader

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I understand how static/dynamic libraries are used by the linker/loader.

1. However why not have a single type of library file accompanied by compiler flags which indicate how the library should be linked (static vs dynamic)?
2. By the simple fact that we do have static and dynamic libraries I presume these files have specific contents which enable static and dynamic linking respectively. Can someone throw some light on the differences between the contents of static and shared library files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a pity the terms *static library* and *dynamic library* are
both of the form *ADJECTIVE library*, because it perpetually leads programmers
to think that they denote variants of the essentially the same kind of thing.
This is almost as misleading as the thought that a badminton court and a supreme court
are essentially the same kind of thing. In fact it's far more misleading,
since nobody actually suffers from thinking that a badminton court and a supreme
court are essentially the same kind of thing.

> Can someone throw some light on the differences between the contents of static and shared library files?

Let's use examples. To push back against the badminton court / supreme court fog
I'm going to use more accurate technical terms. Instead of *static library* I'll say `ar` *archive*, and instead of *dynamic library* I'll say
*dynamic shared object*, or *DSO* for short.

**What an `ar` archive is**

I'll make an `ar` archive starting with these three files:

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo");
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts("bar");
}
```

**limerick.txt**

```
There once was a young lady named bright
Whose speed was much faster than light
She set out one day
In a relative way
And returned on the previous night.
```

I'll compile those two C source into Position Independent object files:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -fPIC foo.c
$ gcc -c -Wall -fPIC bar.c
```

There's no need for object files destined for an `ar` archive to be compiled with
`-fPIC`. I just want these ones compiled that way.

Then I'll create an `ar` archive called `libsundry.a` containing the object files `foo.o` and `bar.o`,
plus `limerick.txt`:

```
$ ar rcs libsundry.a foo.o bar.o limerick.txt
```

An `ar` archive is created, of course, with [`ar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar),
the GNU general-purpose archiver. So *it is not created by the linker*. No linkage
happens. Here's how `ar` reports the contents of the archive:

```
$ ar -t libsundry.a 
foo.o
bar.o
limerick.txt
```

Here's what the limerick in the archive looks like:

```
$ rm limerick.txt
$ ar x libsundry.a limerick.txt; cat limerick.txt
There once was a young lady named bright
Whose speed was much faster than light
She set out one day
In a relative way
And returned on the previous night.
```

**Q.** *What's the point of putting two object files and an ASCII limerick into the same `ar` archive?*

**A.** To show that I can. To show that an `ar` archive is *just a bag of files*.

Let's see what [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) makes of `libsundry.a.`

```
$ file libsundry.a 
libsundry.a: current ar archive
```

Now I'll write a couple of programs that use `libsundry.a` in their linkage.

**fooprog.c**

```
extern void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile, link and run that one:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall fooprog.c
$ gcc -o fooprog fooprog.o -L. -lsundry
$ ./fooprog 
foo
```

That's hunky dory. The linker apparently wasn't bothered by the presence of
an ASCII limerick in `libsundry.a`.

The reason for that is the linker didn't even *try* to link `limerick.txt`
into the program. Let's do the linkage again, this time with a diagnostic option
that will show us exactly what input files are linked:

```
$ gcc -o fooprog fooprog.o -L. -lsundry -Wl,-trace
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o
fooprog.o
(./libsundry.a)foo.o
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Lots of default libraries and object files there, but the only object
files *we* have created that the linker consumed are:

```
fooprog.o
(./libsundry.a)foo.o
```

All that the linker did with `./libsundry.a` was *take* `foo.o` *out of
the bag and link it in the program*. After linking `fooprog.o` into the program,
it needed to find a definition for `foo`.
It looked in the bag. It found the definition in `foo.o`, so it took `foo.o` from
the bag and linked it in the program. In linking `fooprog`,

```
gcc -o fooprog fooprog.o -L. -lsundry
```

is exactly the same linkage as:

```
$ gcc -o fooprog fooprog.o foo.o
```

What does `file` say about `fooprog`?

```
$ file fooprog
fooprog: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), \
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, \
for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=32525dce7adf18604b2eb5af7065091c9111c16e,
not stripped
```

Here's my second program:

**foobarprog.c**

```
extern void foo(void);
extern void bar(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile, link and run:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall foobarprog.c
$ gcc -o foobarprog foobarprog.o -L. -lsundry
$ ./foobarprog 
foo
bar
```

And here's the linkage again with `-trace`:

```
$ gcc -o foobarprog foobarprog.o -L. -lsundry -Wl,-trace
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o
foobarprog.o
(./libsundry.a)foo.o
(./libsundry.a)bar.o
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

So this time, our object files that the linker consumed were:

```
foobarprog.o
(./libsundry.a)foo.o
(./libsundry.a)bar.o
```

After linking `foobarprog.o` into the program, it needed to find definitions for `foo` and `bar`.
It looked in the bag. It found definitions respectively in `foo.o` and  `bar.o`, so it took them from
the bag and linked them in the program. In linking `foobarprog`,

```
gcc -o foobarprog foobarprog.o -L. -lsundry
```

is exactly the same linkage as:

```
$ gcc -o foobarprog foobarprog.o foo.o bar.o
```

Summing all that up. An `ar` archive is *just a bag of files*. You can use
an `ar` archive to offer to the linker a bunch of *object* files from which to
pick the ones that it needs to continue the linkage. It will take those object files
out of the bag and link them into the output file. It has absolutely no other
use for the bag. The bag contributes nothing at all to the linkage.

The bag just makes your life a little simpler by sparing you the need to know
exactly what object files you need for a particular linkage. You only need
to know: *Well, they're in that bag*.

**What a DSO is**

Let's make one.

**foobar.c**

```
extern void foo(void);
extern void bar(void);

void foobar(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

We'll compile this new source file:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -fPIC foobar.c
```

and then make a DSO using `foobar.o` and re-using `libsundry.a`

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.o -L. -lsundry -Wl,-trace
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbeginS.o
foobar.o
(./libsundry.a)foo.o
(./libsundry.a)bar.o
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

That has made the DSO `libfoobar.so`. Notice: *A DSO is made by the linker*. It
is linked just like a program is linked. The linkage of `libfoopar.so` looks very much
like the linkage of `foobarprog`, but the addition of the option
`-shared` instructs the linker to produce a DSO rather than a program. Here we see that our object
files consumed by the linkage were:

```
foobar.o
(./libsundry.a)foo.o
(./libsundry.a)bar.o
```

`ar` does not understand a DSO at all:

```
$ ar -t libfoobar.so 
ar: libfoobar.so: File format not recognised
```

But `file` does:

```
$ file libfoobar.so 
libfoobar.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), \
dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=16747713db620e5ef14753334fea52e71fb3c5c8, \
not stripped
```

Now if we relink `foobarprog` using `libfoobar.so` instead of `libsundry.a`:

```
$ gcc -o foobarprog foobarprog.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-trace,--rpath=$(pwd)
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o
foobarprog.o
-lfoobar (./libfoobar.so)
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

we see

```
foobarprog.o
-lfoobar (./libfoobar.so)
```

that `./libfoobar.so` *itself* was linked. Not some object files "inside it". There
aren't any object files inside it. And how this has
contributed to the linkage can be seen in the dynamic dependencies of the program:

```
$ ldd foobarprog
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca47fb000)
    libfoobar.so => /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/libfoobar.so (0x00007fb050eeb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb050afd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d8119f0000)
```

The program has come out with runtime dependency on `libfoobar.so`. That's what linking a DSO does.
We can see this runtime dependency is satisfied. So the program will run:

```
$ ./foobarprog
foo
bar
```

just the same as before.

The fact that a DSO and a program - unlike an `ar` archive - are both products
of the linker suggests that a DSO and a program *are* variants of the essentially the same kind of thing.
The `file` outputs suggested that too. A DSO and a program are both ELF binaries
that the OS loader can map into a process address space. Not just a bag of files.
An `ar` archive is not an ELF binary of any kind.

The difference between a program-type ELF file and non-program-type ELF lies in the different values
that the linker writes into the ELF Header structure and Program Headers
structure of the ELF file format. These differences instruct the OS loader to
initiate a new process when it loads a program-type ELF file, and to augment
the process that it has under construction when it loads a non-program ELF file. Thus
a non-program DSO gets mapped into the process of its parent program. The fact that a program
initiates a new process requires that a program shall have single default entry point
to which the OS will pass control: that entry point is the mandatory `main` function
in a C or C++ program. A non-program DSO, on the other hand, doesn't need a single mandatory entry point. It can be entered through any of the global functions it exports by function calls from the
parent program.

But from the point of view of file structure and content, a DSO and a program
are very similar things. They are files that can be components of a process.
A program must be the initial component. A DSO can be a secondary component.

It is still common for the further distinction to be made: A DSO must consist entirely
of relocatable code (because there's no knowing at linktime where the loader may need to
place it in a process address space), whereas a program consists of absolute code,
always loaded at the same address. But in fact its quite possible to link a relocatable
*program*:

```
$ gcc -pie -o foobarprog foobarprog.o -L. -lfoobar -Wl,--rpath=$(pwd)
```

That's what `-pie` (Position Independent Executable) does here. And then:

```
$ file foobarprog
foobarprog: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), ....
```

`file` will say that `foobarprog` *is a DSO*, which it is, although it is
*also* still a program:

```
$ ./foobarprog
foo
bar
```

And PIE executables are catching on. In Debian 9 and derivative distros (Ubuntu 17.04...) the GCC toolchain
builds PIE programs *by default*.

If you hanker for detailed knowledge of the `ar` and `ELF` file
formats, here are [details of the `ar` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29#File_format_details)
and here are [details of the ELF format](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf).

> why not have a single type of library file accompanied by compiler flags which 
>   indicate how the library should be linked (static vs dynamic)?

The choice between dynamic and static linkage is already fully controllable by
commandline linkage options, so there's no need abandon either `ar` archives or DSOs or to invent a another kind
of library to achieve this. If the linker couldn't use `ar` archives the way it does,
that would be a considerable inconvenience. And of course if the linker couldn't link
DSOs we'd back to the operating systems stone-age.

Comment: What an epic answer!! Salute!

Answer (score 1):

Because they are completely different things. Static libraries are just collections of compiler-generated object code. Dynamic libraries are linked.

Answer (score 0):

1. The format of dynamic libraries, loaded at run-time, is determined by the operating system writers. The format of static libraries is set by the tool chain writers.  Often there is some overlap between those classes of programmers, but they tend to prefer maintaining separation of concerns.
2. The run-time loader needs to know the size of the image to load, maybe some stack and data segment sizes and the names and entry points of the functions in the DLL.  The linker needs to know a great deal more about each of the objects (functions/data) archived in a static library.  Things like function signatures, data types, sizes of things, initialization, scope of access.

Every OS and tool chain has it's own specific requirements and revision history, so it would not be practical to delineate exact file layouts for all of them here. Refer to the OS and tool chain documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Shareable libraries tend to be compiled into position-independent code. That means, for example, that transfers of control use PC-relative addressing. This is because they might be mapped into different positions in the address spaces of different client programs.

Shareable libraries should have a clear separation between read-only code+data, and read/write data. This way only a single copy of the read-only parts needs to be loaded into memory for all client processes.

If client program A refers to libraries B and C, while library B also refers to C, then you have to make sure that everything is built with consistent shareability settings. For example, if C is built in shareable and non-shareable versions, and B is built shareable against the shareable version of C, then A must also be built against the shareable versions of both B and C. If it tries to use the nonshareable version of C, this will likely lead to build problems, because of the conflict with the shareable version of C being used by B.

[This document](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper (former maintainer of the GNU libc library) goes into more detail than you would ever want to know about shareable libraries.