# Why we need separate library for static and dynamic linking?

Tags: linker

There are related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311882/what-do-statically-linked-and-dynamically-linked-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries).

According to my understanding, static linking directly insert code(what code?machine code?) from library into executables. However, dynamic linking only insert reference(pointer?) point to somewhere in the library.

Then I am wondering why we need two separate version of library of same functionality? For example, for intel MKL, we have libmkl_sequential.a and libmkl_sequential.so. And static linking must link static library, dynamic linking must link dynamic library. **Why dynamic linking can not just simply point to static library?**

**What is the real difference between content of .so and .a of same functionaly?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between static libraries and dynamic libraries ignoring how they are used by the linker/loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116485/differences-between-static-libraries-and-dynamic-libraries-ignoring-how-they-are)

Answer (score 0):

Code which you want to execute needs to be loaded in memory. A function linked statically becomes a part of your program and so they are both loaded together when the program starts.

*Why dynamic linking can not just simply point to static library?* Static library is a disk file, how would you want to point inside this? There must be a mechanism (loader & binder) which investigates the starting executable program, asks which functions it wants to use, and loads the corresponding libraries into memory. 
Yes, the netto code (instructions) in both versions "libmkl_sequential.a" and "libmkl_sequential.so" may be identical, but static and dynamic types of libraries require different auxilliary metainformation dictated by the library format creator.